# What are the six basic primitives in Turing Complete

Tags: turing-machines, turing-complete

I am listening the edX lesson, and the professor stresses that every machine able to perform those six basic primitives can be called Turing Complete. But what are the six basic primitives?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The six basic operations/primitives that gives a language Turing completeness are:

- Right: Move the Machine’s head to the right of the current square
- Left: Move the Machine’s head to the left of the current square
- Print: Print a symbol on the current square
- Scan: Identify any symbols on the current square
- Erase: Erase any symbols presented on the current square
- Nothing/halt: Do nothing

You can learn more at [Alan Turing reference web site](http://www.alanturing.net/turing_archive/pages/reference%20articles/Turing%27s%20O-Machines.html)
and/or watch a [small video about it](https://youtu.be/gJQTFhkhwPA).

Comment: Is this about programming languages, or Turing Machines? They're not the same thing.

Comment: @Marcin This is about Turing O-Machines that are implemented as programming languages.

Comment: @Marcin I'm sorry, it is not. I have studied programming languages for a while now. I wouldn't answer if I didn't study that.

Comment: But, these are not programming language operations. These are turing machine operations.

Comment: for those that want to try writing something using the above primitives this esoteric language has been created: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck

Answer (score 1):

They are the basic of Turing Machine and are composed of

**Right:** Move the Machine’s head to the right of the current square

**Left:** Move the Machine’s head to the left of the current square

**Print:** Print a symbol on the current square

**Scan:** Identify any symbols on the current square

**Erase:** Erase any symbols presented o the current square

**Nothing/HALT:** Do nothing

The idea is that with those six primitives you can program anything.

Comment: This is the same as the answer I posted before.

Comment: @StaticX Yes, but your answer is misleadingly - arguably incorrectly - worded.

Comment: @StaticX When I started typing there wasn't anything + this question is basically "Let me google it for you" he could have found the answer within the first 3-4 results without any previous knowledge in machine learning

Comment: @Wald I agree. I usually research much more before posting a question here. Sadly, many people don't.

Answer (score 0):

Right move ,Left move ,Read ,Write ,erase and donothing

Comment: This answer has nothing to add compared to the accepted one that has been posted years ago. It should be removed.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.